# Mysql has gone away on script that runs for 2 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I have a daemon that I have created and am getting random `Mysql has gone away` errors. I am using `mysql_pconnect` and the script runs for about 2 seconds before I get the error. The query is a very simple query that returns 2 rows. This script runs through the CLI, but anything else through apache never shows this error. Any idea why my script could be timing out like this? I also have an ODBC connection which is doing very similar things!

```
mysql> show variables like "%timeout%";
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout            | 10    |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF   |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30    |
| net_write_timeout          | 60    |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600  |
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50    |
| wait_timeout               | 28800 |
+----------------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `mysql_query`? It's deprecated and being removed from PHP.

Comment: Legacy system and really don't have the time to change it just yet!

Comment: Can you run the same query directly in mysql without issue?

Comment: Yep I can run it without issue. I've found if I add a reconnect to every include file, it works. I don't understand though why the connection is dropping after only a few seconds!